# Zoom one tab or all tabs

Tags: firefox, tabs, zooming

I am looking for a way to **zoom** only one tab.
When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to zoom my Firefox tab, all other tabs are also changed, creating a problem.

I have checked all the menu setting and nothing is available for this setting, at least not from the menu.

Answer (score 15):

1. In Firefox address bar type:   about:config
2. Press the box "I accept the risk" (or similar button)
3. In the Search Box type:    zoom.siteSpecific

If you want Zoom to only effect one tab then set **False** under Value. 
If you want Zoom to effect all tabs then set **True** under Value

You can change the value by double-clicking the line or right-click and select Toggle.

Note: You can restore zoom by selecting CTRL+0 (zero) or on the menu select View --> Zoom --> Reset.